# How to optimize mtext coords and legend spacing in an layout-ed plot?

Tags: r, plot, layout

The headings of the "text" are strangely located at different y-coordinates, although they are defined exactly the same, also the `par`s are the same.

Besides, I want somewhat narrower spacing in the `legend`, `cex` won't help anything.

[image]

I could add some space in `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`-style (see `MARK` in code) which looks somewhat better but doesn't fix the spacing:

[image]

Does anybody know how to deal with that (w/o extra packages)?

The output of the `legend` should look something like this:

[image]

***Code producing plot***

```
# pdf("test.pdf", width=8, height=4)

layout(matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 3), ncol=2), heights=c(4, 1.5))

par(mai=c(0, .5, .5, .25))
plot(1:10)
mtext(bquote(bold("Linear points")), 3, 0, cex=.9, adj=0, padj=-.3)

par(mai=c(0, .5, .5, .25))
curve(x^2)
mtext(bquote(bold("A curve")), 3, 0, cex=.9, adj=0, padj=-.3)

par(mai=c(0, 0, .375, 0))
plot.new()
legend("center", legend=c("The quick", "brown fox", "jumps over",
                          "the lazy dogs",
                          # expression(paste("    ", alpha~"=5%")),  # MARK
                          expression(alpha~"=5%"),
                          "DF=Dgs. of freedom"),
       lty=c(rep(1, 4), rep(NA, 2)), bg="white", col=1:4,
       xpd=TRUE, pt.cex=1.1, horiz=TRUE, cex=.7)

# dev.off()
```

Comment: The first one (vertical mis-alignment of `mtext`) is "fixed" if both titles have either no drop-letters or both have one or more drop-letters. If you add a "p" or similar to the second title, you can see this. Not sure how best to add a phantom drop-letter to encourage the alignment ...

Comment: `bquote(bold("A curve") * phantom("p"))` is a workaround, though is does take up horizontal space (anything after the `phantom("p")` will be right-shifted).

Comment: The `legend` spacing is based on equi-distance for the lines. The fact that you hide the lines on the right two does not affect this, the equidistance is preserved on where the line *would* be. What precisely is the anticipated result? If you want equal spacing *between* entries, you have to create each legend entry individually (which is possible but arduous).

Comment: (If you change one of the lined legend entries to be much shorter/longer than the others, you'll see what I'm talking about.)

Comment: @r2evans You're right, I have a `j` in one header that lift things up.`phantom` is really awesome, thanks! `padj=` is not bad either. For the legend, if I understand things right, it's arranged in a table grid with equal sized columns? I've found no option to define column width, e.g. `c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2)`. I've added a output how the legend would look nicest (note the small extra space right after "Dg. of freedom").

Comment: Since `legend` does not seem to support what you need, you may have to resort to using `strwidth` and determine widths of things and generate all of it manually. As an alternative, perhaps two legends: `legend("left", ..., lty=rep(1,4), ...)`, and `legend("right", c(expresssion(alpha~"=5%"),...))`. Depending on the whole layout, this might give more space to the left of alpha, but it would separate the two groups (which is a good thing, given the context I've seen).

Comment: @r2evans Followed your suggestions, `box.col=0` used for right legend, looks great now, thx!